# How do I use a nested arrays to draw a grid?

Tags: d3.js

I'm pretty new to d3. I have this and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var w = 620;
  var h = 30;

  var father = [ true, true, false, false, false ];

  //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("#parentsmed")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("width", w);

  var fatherrects = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(father)
      .enter()
      .append("rect");

  fatherrects.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 31) + 93;
      })
       .attr("width", 30)
       .attr("height",30)
       .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        if(father[i] == true) {
          return "#89CFF0";
        } else {
          return "#efefef";
        }
       });

</script>
```

What I would like to do is have either another array var or a nested array and also draw the 'mother' values... Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var w = 620;
  var h = 30;

  var father = [ true, true, false, false, false ];
  var mother = [ false, true, false, false, true ];

  //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("#parentsmed")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("width", w);

  var fatherrects = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(father)
      .enter()
      .append("rect");

  fatherrects.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 31) + 93;
      })
       .attr("width", 30)
       .attr("height",30)
       .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        if(father[i] == true) {
          return "#89CFF0";
        } else {
          return "#efefef";
        }
       });


  var motherrects = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(mother)
      .enter()
      .append("rect");

  motherrects.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 31) + 93;
      })
       .attr("y", 31)
       .attr("width", 30)
       .attr("height",30)
       .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        if(mother[i] == true) {
          return "#89CFF0";
        } else {
          return "#efefef";
        }
       });
</script>
```

This draws the `fatherrects`, but not the `motherrects`. How can I get it to draw both (father rects on the top row, mother rects on the bottom row), either using two array vars, as shown, or a single `var data = [father,mother];` nested array?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting the same `<rect>` elements in both the father and the mother cases. Since you aren't providing a key function in the data bind the key defaults to array index, which will be the same for both the mother and father array.  Same nodes plus same bind key means you're updating the father nodes with mother data (and the `enter()` selection will be empty).

If you add a "father" class to the father nodes and a "mother" class to the mother nodes, you can keep them separate in your selection.  For example:

```
 var motherrects = svg.selectAll("rect.mother")
    .data(mother)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "mother");
```

Another option is to pass a key function into the `data` call, but this will involve modifying your data so it contains something you can use as a key.  Keeping the nodes distinct by classing them is easier and probably more correct.

Yet another option would be to use the 2D array you suggest (`[father, mother]`) and then  group the rects from each subarray in their own `<g>`:

```
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("rect");
```

This makes use of the grouping structure of selections.  The value of `d` in the `data` function will be the father array in the first invocation and then the mother array in the second and the rects will be created under the corresponding `<g>` element.