# How to write two different text in different axis?

Tags: d3.js

I have to write text/labels in two different axis. This is my data size and I want to print hello and name in both axis depending on the array. But now only one axis is printing. Please help me out:

```
enter code here

<script>
  var dat =[1,2,3];
  var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height",500)
    .attr("width",1000)
  var x=10 ; var y=30; var space =50;
  var x1=0 ; var y1=30;
  var gene =canvas.selectAll("text")
    .data(dat)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x",function(d){x=x+space; return x; })
    .attr("y",30)
    .text("hello")
  var gene2 =canvas.selectAll("text")
    .data(dat)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("x",function(d){return x1; })
    .attr("y",function(d) {y1=y1+space; return y1; })
    .text("name")
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do. Could you elaborate? What exactly isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: i have to create a svg image where in i have to write "hello " on the top of the image(x-axis) and write "name vertically(y -axis)

Comment: There are many examples on the D3 website. Is there nothing that meets your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not differentiating between the 2 groups of `<text>` elements.  The code creates the nodes with the first data bind, and then it selects these same nodes and binds the same data (using the same default bind key) again, which will simply update the data on the existing nodes (that is, the `enter()` selection will be empty).

This is a similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985819/1040479). There are a few options for resolving it described there.

Comment: hi thanks it had worked for me... Can you also please suggest me some books/ websites which would help me to learn from basics to implementations

Comment: I don't know about books but the main d3 website (http://d3js.org/) has a nice little overview and links to a ton of great tutorials.